# How to read a txt file and show it as a table in a console application?

Tags: c#

I am sorry if i worded to question wrongly and caused confusion. But here is what I want to do. I want the program to read the txt file and then arrange the data into like a table format?

The txt file can look something like this:

```
fullname1|ID1|age1|mark1
fullname2|ID2|age2|mark2
fullname3|ID3|age3|mark3
```

I have looked up several ways to do it but none of them worked for me, and I am self learning C# but my English is limited so it is hard for me to look for deeper solution.

Comment: It looks like you effectively have a CSV file with pipe (`|`) as the delimiter instead of comma (`,`). You could probably use a library like CsvHelper.Io to read the file.

Comment: What is your expected output? What you tried so far?

Comment: Your input looks like it is already in a tabular form. What is the actual output that you want?

Comment: This is a composite question. You need to break the problem down into smaller parts. 1) Read the file. 2) Display the data.

Comment: I expect the output to be like a table with columns @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: @John ty! i will look into it!

Comment: @madreflection aaa ty i will take note for future reference

Comment: @Enigmativity I want it to print out in the console app as like a table so what i am trying to do now is instead of a database i use the text file, if that makes sense

Comment: @notCloud - No, it doesn't. In your question you show us the text file you're reading. It already looks like it is in tabular form. What is the difference between what you want and the source text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because i'm bored

**Given**

```
fullname1|ID1|age1|mark1546
sdfdsf|ID2|age56|mark2
gfhxcxvxcvxc|ID3|age3|mark3
```

**Code**

```
// read lines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Data.txt")
                .Select(x => x.Split('|'))
                .ToArray();

// calculate column widths
var widths = Enumerable.Range(0, lines[0].Length)
                       .Select(x => lines.Max(y => y[x].Length))
                       .ToArray();

// Write the lines with padding each column with its max width
foreach (var line in lines)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", line.Select((x,i) => x.PadRight(widths[i], ' '))));
```

**Output**

```
fullname1   , ID1, age1 , mark1546
sdfdsf      , ID2, age56, mark2
gfhxcxvxcvxc, ID3, age3 , mark3
```

<sub>***DISCLAIMER*** : obviously this makes assumptions, therefor i am not responsible for the people you potentialy maim or otherwise harm with this code</sub>